# Maximize a1^a2^a3…^an where a1,a2,…,an is a permutation of {b1,b2,…,bn}

Tags: math, set, maximize

Maximize a1^a2^a3…^an where a1,a2,…,an is a permutation of {b1,b2,…,bn}
Here is the complete description of the question

```
  you are given set B = {b1,b2..................bn} .
    Return permutation of B which maximizes a1^a2^a3........^an
    where a1,a2,........,an is a permutation of {b1,b2,......,bn}.
```

For Example -

```
if set B  = {5, 6, 4}
then ans should be {6 ,5, 4}
if set b = {2,3}
then ans should be {2,3}
```

Edit -

- ^ is power operator.
- Let me clarify little more. I liked the problem very much and I was
  able to solve it by finding the pattern.I am posting it here for 2
  reasons 1). to get better reasoning for answer 2). for people.

Existing solution-

By induction i found that

```
a^b < b^a when a and b are not 3 and a>b  
and a^b > b^a reverse otherwise.
```

I am not able to mathematically prove this statement

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's clearly an homework question, without any effort shown by the poster.

Comment: @Blackhole: nor was there any effort to define what the "^" operator is, nor is it programming related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @Pang Its programming question. It was asked in one of the programming competitions.

Comment: @Blackhole Its not homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.Sharing the answer for audience-

1. Sort the numbers b1,b2,...,b_n$ in decreasing order.Lets call it Seq.
2. Let answer be A. All the 1s to A and remove them from Seq.
   i.e If Seq is 4,3,2,1,1
   then after step 2 seq will be 2,3,4
   and A = 1,1
3. if first element in Seq is 3 and second element is 2 then remove both from Seq and add 2,3 to A
4. Add rest of the elements from Seq to A.

Let me know if you find anything wrong in given solution.